# Trying to use strtok and malloc but keeps erroring and I cannot see the error message

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, strtok

I'm trying to create a split function using strtok and a dynamic array.
However, I have no clue where things are going wrong: No informative error messages.
It does say segmentation fault, but I don't understand how the heap is corrupt or whatever causes that happens.
Would someone be willing to explain to me what is wrong and how to do it correctly?

Edit 11:16 CST code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **toArray(char **array, char str[], char sep[], int *count);
char** my_split(const char* str, char delim, int* size);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* test = "Hello there lol";
    int *count = 0;
    char **array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 5);
    toArray(array, test, " ", count);
    printf("Count: %d\n", *count);

    int array_i;
    for (array_i = 0; array_i < *count; array_i++) {
        printf("array %d: %s\n", array_i, array[array_i]);
        free(array[array_i]);
    }
    free(array);
    return 1;
}

char **toArray(char **array, char str[], char sep[], int *count) {
    char *temp = str;
    temp = strtok(temp, sep);
    array[0] = temp;
    *count = 1;
    while ((temp = strtok(NULL, sep)) != NULL ) {
        array[(*count)++] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any compile warnings? That `while ((*temp = strtok(NULL, sep)) != NULL) {` looks wrong.

Comment: @Dennis No compile errors, everything works during compile. Some warnings about not casting things, but it compiles.

Comment: @Charlie this is better? toArray(**array, test, " ", count); but nothing different runtime.

Comment: `while ((*temp = strtok(NULL, sep)) != NULL)` _should be_ `while ((temp = strtok(NULL, sep)) != NULL)`  (removed *)

Comment: @user2875342 Pay attention to those warnings; they can uncover other problems too.

Comment: in the section:  `toArray(**array, test, " ", *count);`, you are trying to pass **array, but array is typed as a char **, and the argument is prototyped to accept a char **,  so you should only pass `array`, like this: (same kind of thing with count),  `toArray(array, test, " ", count);`

Comment: @DennisMeng I got rid of all the warning on compile with gcc -Wall -g but nothing happens for runtime

Comment: @ryyker Also nothing happens. To all most of these stars (dereferences?) have been going in and out of the code as I tried to troubleshoot and nothing different happens most of the time when I tried it before.

Comment: @user2875342 What about if you include `-pedantic` and `-Wextra`?

Comment: New code 11:16 CST has not compilation warnings with gcc -Wall -g

Comment: @DennisMeng With pedantic and Wextra flags only warnings are about unused argc and argv. Also something about mixing the array_i and *count near the for loop that prints the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler messages are our friend. I simpley used them to track down your issues.   ***Try the following***, and compare whats been done to what you had.  Special attention to decalration and usage of pointer variables...  :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char **toArray(char **array, char str[], char sep[], int *count);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char test[] = "Hello there lol";
    int count = 0;
    char **array = malloc((sizeof(char*) * 5) +1); //added "+ 1" here, read why
    toArray(array, test, " ", &count);             //in comment below
    printf("Count: %d\n", count);

    int array_i;
    for (array_i = 0; array_i < count; array_i++) {
        printf("array %d: %s\n", array_i, array[array_i]);
        //free(array[array_i]);
    }
    getchar();
    free(array);
    return 1;
}

char **toArray(char **array, char str[], char sep[], int *count) {
    char *temp = str;
    temp = strtok(temp, sep);
    array[0] = temp;
    *count = 1;
    while ((temp = strtok(NULL, sep)) != NULL) {
        array[(*count)++] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

[EDIT] ***Example Output:***
[image]

***Also***.  The line `char **array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 5);`, needed to be 
`char **array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 5 + 1);`  because "hello" is actually 5 chars plus a NULL char, `'\0'`.

***Some rules of thumb for*** *C string(s)*.

***1)*** when using malloc or calloc, don't forget to allow room for `'\0'`.

```
     `char *buf1;` //buffer needed to manipulate buf2  
     `char  buf2[]="someString";`  
     `buf1 = malloc(strlen(buf2)+1);` or `buf1 = malloc(sizeof(buf2));`    
                                         (note:, no '+1'.  see '4)' below. )
```

***2)*** clear (initialize) new allocated variable before use.  eg:

```
memset(buf, 0, strlen("someString")+1);  //preferred, all bytes are zeroed
```

***OR***

```
buf[0]=0;  //useful, but use with care (only first byte is zeroed.)
```

***3)*** Free all dynamically allocated memory when done with it.  Eg:

```
free(buf);
```

***4)*** Using `strlen()` function or `sizeof()` macro.  (both popular for use in `[mc]alloc()`)
***Given:***
char *buf1   ="Hello"; //6 characters  `|H|e|l|l|o|\0|`
char  buf2[] ="Hello"; //6 characters  `|H|e|l|l|o|\0|`
char  buf3[5]="Hello"; //5 characters  `|H|e|l|l|o|`
char  buf4[5]="Hel";   //4 characters  `|H|e|l|\0| |`
char  buf5[5]="Helloo";//should get compile error, too many initializers

***Compare `strlen() - sizeof()` results:***

`strlen(buf1); //->5` (requires +1 in malloc for new variable req'd to hold "Hello\0")
`sizeof(buf1); //->4` (returns sizof (char *), not # chars in string)

`strlen(buf2); //->5` (requires +1 in malloc for new variable req'd yo hold "Hello\0")
`sizeof(buf2); //->6` (counts all chars, including '\0')

`strlen(buf3); //->`  (error: Missing terminating NULL in string argument)
`sizeof(buf3); //->5` (counts all chars, but there is no '\0' in this string - wrong!)

`strlen(buf4); //->3` (counts chars, but not '\0')
`sizeof(buf4); //->5` (counts ALL allocated space, including '\0')

Comment: Your code doesn't print anything out? Nothing in console. I did get rid of the warnings, but by editing the code not turning them off or anything. I have no clue what the getchar() is for?

Comment: I will edit my post with my output.  In my settings, I use `getchar()` just to hold the execution so I can see my output until I hit a key, then it all goes away.  See my edit in just a minute for output.  You may have to use some other technique, perhaps `getch()`?

Comment: "One other thing, in the line char **array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 5);, it is still allocated wrong (as Charlie will soon point out if we do not)." What is this not the top level of the array? I tried it with 15 character parts and it still works. Doesn't that only apply to the second level such as array[0] =malloc(number)?

Comment: I made that comment just as a general caution to pay attention to include space for the NULL char.  The string you are parsing is:  `char test[] = "Hello there lol";`. It is essentially 3 words, two of them have 5 chars, one of them 3.  You need to include an extra space for a null termination when the variable array is populated with them, in particular the 5 char words.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `char *test = "Hello there lol";` to your `toArray()`. Unfortunately, the string is not modifiable, so when you try to modify it with `strtok()`, you get a segmentation fault.

The simplest fix is:

```
char test[] = "Hello there lol";
```

You also have:

```
int *count = 0;
```

and you call the function with:

```
toArray(array, test, " ", count);
```

You need an integer, and to pass its address:

```
int count = 0;
...
toArray(array, test, " ", &count);
```

You were also trying to free the strings that were pointed at by the elements in `array`, but those were never allocated (they are parts of the string `test`).  Don't free what was not allocated with `malloc()` et al.

With those fixes in place, this code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **toArray(char **array, char str[], char sep[], int *count);

int main(void)
{
    char test[] = "Hello there lol";
    int count = 0;
    char **array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5);

    toArray(array, test, " ", &count);
    printf("Count: %d\n", count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("array %d: %s\n", i, array[i]);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}

char **toArray(char **array, char str[], char sep[], int *count)
{
    char *temp = str;
    temp = strtok(temp, sep);
    array[0] = temp;
    *count = 1;
    while ((temp = strtok(NULL, sep)) != NULL)
        array[(*count)++] = temp;
    return array;
}
```

Output:

```
Count: 3
array 0: Hello
array 1: there
array 2: lol
```